# can anyone give me a simple example source using CollectionFS(Meteor.js)

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

hello guys i'm a noob to the Meteor framework and web development

Recently i want to implement upload and download page using CollectionFS package in Meteorite

so i read documentation on

https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#cfsfileurl

but i could not apprehend how to use this library

and there's only a example with an implemented webpage not a source code.

i would like to see fully implemented simple project source using CollectionFS

can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the source code for the live example:
https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-example-filemanager

and here are some others:
https://github.com/mxab/cfsfileurl-example
https://github.com/mxab/cfs-multi-filehandler-example

All are from the README, btw... did you not find these useful?

Comment: cfsfileurl-example and cfs-multi don't work because of  Unexpected mongo exit code 1